# Using the minimax algorithm, how do I access the node that returned the best value so it can be utilised?

Tags: c++, minimax

I am currently completing an assignment for a uni paper. I am making an AI for a checkers game. I understand the principles of the minimax algorithm, however, when it came to implementing it I am struggling to see how I can access the node with the best move so it can be implemented. It may be that I have implemented the code incorrectly which, has put me in this situation. However, as far as I can see it is only returning the best score that was evaluated. How do I then get the node that returned it to the Root?

This is the code for the GameTree that has the minimax function in it. I want to be able to use the node that sent the best score in the GetNextMove()

```
#include "gametree.h"
//Constructor
GameTree::GameTree()
{

}

/* This function is part of the evalutaion of which move is best by looking for the best
 * score in the tree. which is set up by the nodes calling themselves via the Move::PosMove
 *  function. This function was used because it was taught in class and it enables pruning. 
 *  this function goes down the left side to the bottom of the tree first. Because the 
 *  children of each node are stored in a set the highest score is the first to be seen.
 *  this will enable maximum pruning, so will speed up the search for the best move.
 *  Called by Move::AiMove() */
int GameTree::minimax(Node *node, int depth, int alpha, int beta, bool isMaxNode)
{
    int Alpha = alpha;
    int Beta = beta;
    
    if (depth == 0|| endGame ==1)
    {
        nScore= node->score;
        return nScore;
    }
    if (isMaxNode)
    {
        int HighScore = -1000;
        for (int i =0; i< (int)node->children.size(); i++)
        {
            nScore= minimax(node, depth-1, Alpha, Beta, false);
            HighScore= max(HighScore,nScore);
            Alpha= max(Alpha, HighScore);
            if (beta<=alpha)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return Alpha;
    }

    else
    {
        int LowScore = 1000;
        for (int i =0; i< (int)node->children.size(); i++)
        {
            nScore= minimax(node,depth-1, Alpha, Beta, true);
            LowScore= min(LowScore,nScore);
            Beta= min(Beta, LowScore);
            if (beta<=alpha)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return Beta;
    }
}

/* This function serches for the best move based on teh minimax evaluation by looking at
 *  the children of the root node.
 *  Called By Move::AiMove() */
void GameTree::GetNextMove()
{
    nodeNext = *nodeRoot->children.begin();
    for (Node *n : nodeRoot->children)
    {
        if (n->score > nodeNext->score)
        {
            nodeNext = n;
        }
    }
    nodeNext->UpdateDisplay(4);
    return;

}
```

Thank you, in advance for your help I have received a lot of help from this website, without ever having to ask a question. Hopefully, you can help me again. Thanks.

Comment: I am writing the code in the Qt ide and using C++.

Comment: You are analyzing the positions only at the leaves, these node values will percolate down up to to the root to select the best move.

Comment: Thanks, @seccpur, that much I could follow. What code do I need to implement to access the child of the root node, in the GetNextMove( ) function, that will lead to the best move path at the end of the tree? At the moment it looks like it will only search the root nodes children for the best score not taking into consideration the minimax results.

Comment: Keep the position information and the score in a structure. So you have the highest score as well as the move key. See some example on github like GNU chess or chess88.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not show AiMove() it is difficult to answer correctly. However one basic way is to write a minimax algorithm in AiMove that catches when the best score has been beaten.

```
void AiMove(){
    //Make all the moves for the ROOT
    //Compute the alpha-beta value of all moves :
    int alpha = -INF, beta = INF;
    Node* nodeNext;
    for(Node* n : nodeRoot->children){
         int cur = minimax(n, depth-1, alpha, beta, false);
         n->score = cur; //Warning, not necessarily the real score for this node
         if(cur > alpha){ //Wow ! new high score
              alpha = cur;
              nodeNext = n; // here you go
         }
    }
    //GetNextMove(); //useless now
}
```

Some corrections of your minimax functions :

```
int GameTree::minimax(Node *node, int depth, int alpha, int beta, bool isMaxNode)
{
    //int Alpha = alpha; No need of Alpha and Beta, alpha and beta are the very one used
    //int Beta = beta;

    if (depth == 0|| endGame ==1)
    {
        nScore= node->score;
        return nScore;
    }

    //Warning : you need to generate all children of node here only

    if (isMaxNode)
    {
        int HighScore = -1000;
        for (int i =0; i< (int)node->children.size(); i++)
        {
            nScore= minimax(node->children[i], depth-1, Alpha, Beta, false); //mistake here
            HighScore= max(HighScore,nScore);
            Alpha= max(Alpha, HighScore);
            if (beta<=alpha)  //mistake here : Alpha or alpha? use the varying variable in the function
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return Alpha;
    }

    else
    {
        int LowScore = 1000;
        for (int i =0; i< (int)node->children.size(); i++)
        {
            nScore= minimax(node,depth-1, Alpha, Beta, true); //mistake here too
            LowScore= min(LowScore,nScore);
            Beta= min(Beta, LowScore);
            if (beta<=alpha) //Same here
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return Beta;
    }
}
```

Finally, for efficiency you don't want to use a Node structure, because then every Node is saved in the memory and it takes some time. One faster way is to work on the board directly. This looks something like that in the minimax function. There will be nothing saved.

```
for each possible move:
    apply(move);
    minimax(depth-1, alpha, beta); //Recursively compute the minimax value
    //Do stuffs on alpha and beta
    undo(move);
```